# How to show that ranking is maintained across conditions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking

Let's say I have four different classrooms of students, and they all take two tests. How do I show that the ranking of the classrooms is maintained across the two tests? e.g. classroom 3 does the best, followed by classroom 2, classroom 1, and then classroom 4, and this is the same for both tests.

Additionally, is there a way to do this which also takes into account the actual values of the scores for each student?

Comment: I guess... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test Second question - I better not to. Usually marks are not "continuous", they are ordinal (e.g. getting 60 points is not 60% of 100 points). I'd better keep with ranks.

Comment: this was what i was looking for - thanks!